# How to find what's new in VC++ v10?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

Googling nor binging "VC++ What's new C++0x" gives me nothing that tells me what is new.Is there an official page at msdn or something similiar that contains the information for VC++ 10? I've seen such for C#,there must be one for what I'd enjoy to read.

If not, please list the new features available in Visual Studio 2010 for VC++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/default.aspx) has frequent articles about what's new for VC++ in Studio 2010.  It's not an exhaustive list, but does detail many of the new additions.

There's also [an MS site](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010/default.mspx) which lists some of whats new.

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia's Visual C++ page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B) has a recap, which I imagine will be updated frequently as we get closer to the release:

> Visual C++ 2010 (known also as Visual
> C++ 10.0) is planned for release on
> April 12, 2010. It is currently in
> development, and available publicly
> only in the form of beta version, and
> available on MSDN as a release
> candidate. The Visual C++ team is
> considering using a SQL Server Compact
> database to store information about
> the source code, including
> IntelliSense information, for better
> IntelliSense and code-completion
> support. This version adds a
> modern C++ parallel computing library
> called the Parallel Patterns Library,
> partial support for C++0x,
> significantly improved IntelliSense,
> and performance improvements to both
> the compiler and generated code.
> This version is built around .NET 4.0,
> but supports compiling to machine
> code. The partial C++0x support in
> VC10 consists of 6 compiler features
> (lambdas, rvalue references, auto,
> decltype, static_assert, nullptr), and
> some library features (e.g. moving the
> TR1 components from std::tr1 namespace
> directly to std namespace). Variadic
> templates were also considered, but
> delayed until some future version due
> to lower priority which stemmed from
> the fact that unlike other
> costly-to-implement features in VC10
> (lambda, rvalue references), this one
> would benefit rather the minority of
> library writers than the majority of
> compiler end users.
>
> - Beta 2 version number: 16.00.21003.01 (this is the version of compiler; the IDE itself has version number 16.00.21006.01)
> - RC version number: 16.00.30128.01