# Visual-C++ 2008 vs Visual-C++ 2010 - what has changed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find what’s new in VC++ v10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822223/how-to-find-whats-new-in-vc-v10)

Visual-C++ 2008 vs Visual-C++ 2010 - what has changed? What are + and - of new VC++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822223/how-to-find-whats-new-in-vc-v10